# How do I run a Django 1.6 project with multiple instances running off the same server, using the same db backend?

Tags: python, django, deployment, paas

I have a Django 1.6 project (stored in a Bitbucket Git repo) that I wish to host on a VPS.

The idea is that when someone purchases a copy of the software I have written, I can type in a few simple commands that will take a designated copy of the code from Git, create a new instance of the project with its own subdomain (e.g. <customer_name>.example.com), and create a new Postgres database (on the same server).

I should hopefully be able to create and remove these 'instances' easily.

What's the best way of doing this?
I've looked into writing scripts using some sort of combination of Supervisor/Gnunicorn/Nginx/Fabric etc. Other options could be something more serious like using Docker or Vagrant. I've also looked into various PaaS options too.

Thanks in advance.

(**EDIT:** I have looked at the following services/things: Dokku (can't use Heroku due to data constraints), Vagrant (inc Puppet), Docker, Fabfile, Deis, Cherokee, Flynn (under dev))

Answer (score 2):

If I was doing it (and I did a similar thing with a PHP application I inherited), I'd have a fabric command that allows me to provision a new instance.

This could be broken up into the requisite steps (check-out code, create database, syncdb/migrate, create DNS entry, start web server).

I'd probably do something sane like use the DNS entry as the database name: or at least use a reversible function to do that.

You could then string these together to easily create a new instance.

You will also need a way to tell the newly created instance which database and domain name they needed to use. You could have the provisioning script write some data to a file in the checked out repository that is then used by Django in it's initialisation phase.